# Convert div to printable object in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, printing, type-conversion

Here is my div:

```
<div id="myDIV">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

I want to print `myDIV` on server printer,
not on client side.

So I think I have to use PrintDocument. Is that correct?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument print;
    print = new PrintDocument();
    print.PrintPage += Print_PrintPage;
    print.Print();
}

private void Print_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World!", new Font("Arial", 30), Brushes.Gold, 90, 20);    
}
```

I used that code to print strings on server printer, but I don't know how to convert div as printhandler object.

I'd appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Convert your div to server runnable by adding `runat="server"` then you can call this div in your code behind

Comment: thanks. can you tell me how to print that div?

Comment: Use `string contents = myDIV.innerHTML;` to get the contents and pass it to your printing method

Comment: Cannot get inner content of "myDIV" because the contents are not literal. - HttpException

Comment: Do you want to print the button and Label as well?

Comment: yes. and gridview too.